# C# Change properties of control added at runtime to winform

Tags: c#, runtime, progress-bar

I need to add a variable number of progress bars to a form and then update them as required. I can add the progress bars fine, but cannot find a way to update their properties.

```
int pbCount = 0;
void AddProgressBar(int, pbX, int pbY, int initalValue) 
{
    pbCount++;
    ProgressBar MyBar = new ProgressBar();
    MyBar.Name = "MyBar" + pbCount.ToString();
    MyBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(pbX, pbY);
    MyBar.Width = 200;
    MyBar.Height = 20;
    MyBar.Minimum = 0;
    MyBar.Maximum = 100;
    MyBar.Value = initialValue;
    this.Controls.Add(MyBar);
}
```

So how do I change the value of a given Progress Bar?

Or is there a better way of adding the Progress Bars for updating later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProgressBar bar7 = this.Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == "MyBar7" );
```

If it doesn't find "MyBar7" it will return null.

Then you can update properties as needed.

Another option would be to also store the progress bars in a `Dictionary< string, ProgressBar >;`

Here is an example using LinqPad:

It shows how to add a new ProgressBar to the dictionary, and how to get it from the dictionary.

You could probably also just use a simple array if you want to access the ProgressBars by index.

```
Dictionary<string,ProgressBar> ProgressBars = new Dictionary<string,ProgressBar>();

void Main()
{
    ProgressBars["MyBar1"] = new ProgressBar();

    //... later on
    ProgressBar progressBar = ProgressBars["MyBar1"];
    progressBar.PerformStep();
    progressBar.Step = 77;

    progressBar.Step.Dump();

}
```

Comment: This put me on the right path, I ended up with (note parenthesis after "<ProgressBar>":                                                                         ProgressBar pbar = this.Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == mybar);

Comment: Forgot to note that "mybar" is a string containing the name of the progress bar of interest...